# Virtual directory not configured as an iis application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I know there are many questions already like this but I tried many solutions but nothing is working.

ERROR
An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

I tried to configured it in iis but still not working

**UPDATE**
Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension, LongDate" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[ERROR PAGE LINK](http://surajcreator.com/quista/index.aspx)

Please help to fix it..

Comment: Did you set the customError in the web.config and did you create a custom view for the error page?

Comment: @Gnqz Thanks for your reply. I have updated post. Posted web.config. Please refer and help me..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try browsing the website in the server and share the exact error. This might be because in IIS the virtual directory is not configured with proper app-pool.

Comment: Can you share the screenshots of IIS settings, the virtual directory and check if an app-pool is assigned properly to the virtual directory.